# Jquery Active Menu Highlighter

Tags: jquery, highlighting

I'm making a one page website with sticky nav. What i want is when the select menu has been clicked the active link is highlighted with different color. this is my jquery script:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    var pathname = (window.location.pathname.match(/[^\/]+$/)[0]);
    $("#main-menuid li a").removeClass("current");
    $("#main-menuid li a[href='" + pathname  + "']").addClass("current");
});
```

My navigation HTML:

```
<div id="main-menuid">
<ul>
<li class="homnav"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
<li class="abonav"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
<li class="mennav"><a href="#menu">Menu</a></li>
<li class="connav"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

And my CSS for class .current:

```
.current {
    color: #F05454;
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's not working at all, did i miss something?

Comment: Try an `alert` or `console.log` on your `pathname` variable - what value are you getting?

Comment: Follow ipr101's advice to see about getting a proper pathname. Or just use Firebug/Dev Tools to see if .current has been applied! It might be that the class is there, but the CSS isn't working because it doesn't have high enough specificity or something.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use window.location.hash to get the #parameter

Try with the following code.

```
   var pathname = window.location.hash;
    $("#main-menuid li a").removeClass("current");
    $("#main-menuid li a[href='" + pathname  + "']").addClass("current");

            jQuery("#main-menuid a").click(function(){
                 $("#main-menuid li a").removeClass("current");
                 $(this).addClass("current");
            })

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it’s hashes, you can probably just do the highlighting on click. Then just filter out the matching hash and add the class onload (anchors have the same properties as window.location):

```
var c = 'current';
$("ul a").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass(c).parent().siblings().children('.'+c).removeClass(c);
}).filter(function() {
    return this.hash == location.hash;
}).addClass(c);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KL7QZ/